# Using array_intersect with multidimesional arrays and different keys

Tags: php, arrays

Having this array (`$firstArray`):

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(3) "foo"
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "1064"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(3) "boo"
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "1070"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(3) "bar"
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "1081"
 }
```

And this one (`$secondArray`):

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "1064"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "1081"
}
```

How can I use `array_intersect` on these inner arrays?

I tried `array_intersect($firstArray, $secondArray);` which is not working.

My desired output would be:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(3) "foo"
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "1064"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(3) "bar"
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "1081"
 }
```

PS: I'm using PHP 5.2 (I cant update the version as it's not my own machine)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `array_intersect` on two arrays with different structures. To achieve your goal, you have to loop through your first array and check if the `id` value is in the second array, as such :

```
$outputArray = array();

foreach ($firstArray as $value) {
    if (in_array($value['id'], $secondArray))
        $outputArray[] = $value;
}
```